Not getting continuous motion data with Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense Rev2 on Google's Tiny motion trainer
I'm using an Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense Rev2 with the Tiny Motion Trainer by Google to train for certain movements. The original code was designed for the Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense, which uses the LSM9DS1 IMU sensor. I have modified the code to use the BMI270_BMM150 sensor (updated the library in dataprovide.cpp from #include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h> to #include <Arduino_BMI270_BMM150.h>).
However, after running the code and visualizing motion on the Tiny Motion Trainer, I observe a non-continuous graph compared to what is shown in YouTube tutorials. I've attached images for reference.
My data:

Expected data:

Link to images
I suspect this issue might be due to the difference in data output frequency between the LSM9DS1 (119 Hz) and the BMI270_BMM150 (99 Hz). However, I couldn't find anything in the code referencing this directly.
Could the frequency difference be causing this issue?  If not, what else could be causing the non-continuous graph as all the tutorial I have seen for this, the people are getting continuous graphs.

what do you mean by continuous motion data? ... how do you know that the arduino is not sending it?

@jsotola If you look at my graph there are points when the motion is 0 while I am moving the sensor continuously compared to one in tutorial where the graph is continuous.
